# Controlling Widget Placement inside PyQt QFormLayout

Tags: python, pyqt, qtgui, qlistwidget

A simple `QtGui.QListWidget` is placed inside of a `QtGui.QFormLayout`.

This list widget's sides are beautifully stick to the side edges of the main dialog box but not to the dialog's bottom or top edge. The list widget re-sizes itself only when a main dialog window gets wider or slimmer and not when it gets taller and shorter.

**How can we make a widget placed inside of `QFormLayout` stick to the bottom edge of the dialog window?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `QSizePolicy.setVerticalStretch`:

```
import PyQt4.QtGui as gui

app = gui.QApplication([])

w = gui.QWidget()

la = gui.QFormLayout()
w.setLayout(la)

tw = gui.QTreeWidget()
sp = tw.sizePolicy()
sp.setVerticalStretch(1)
tw.setSizePolicy(sp)

la.addWidget(tw)

w.show()

app.exec_()
```